# UILabel does not render in prototype cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UIViewController that contains a UITableView. In my table view I have a prototype cell in which I want to place custom labels. I cannot get any of my custom labels to render in the cell. The datasource and tableview delegates are connected and functioning properly. For my first attempt, I dragged a UILabel control onto my prototype cell. I set its tag to 1000. Here is my code to populate the cells:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellID = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    UILabel *customLbl = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1000];
    if(indexPath.section == 0){
        [cell.textLabel setText:[rData.currentHeightReadings objectForKey:[heightKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
        [customLbl setText:@"CFS"];
    } else {
        [cell.textLabel setText:[rData.currentFlowReadings objectForKey:[flowKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
        [customLbl setText:@"Ft."];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

The default textLabel for each cell renders as it should. However, the custom label does not appear. I verified that the prototype cell was actually rendering by changing the background color of the cell's content view. In my story board I have set the prototype cell's reuse identifier to match my code. The style is set to 'Custom.' What else should I be doing? Thanks!

Comment: try [customLbl setNeedsDisplay]

Comment: Is your `customLb` actually getting proper reference to the element or is it `nil`?

Comment: The label is showing a valid instance and is set to the correct text. It just won't show up on the cell.

Comment: Temporarily change the background the colour of the UILabel in your prototype, us that to see if the label is actually on the screen and not being hidden by one of the other labels

Comment: Are you using autolayout or size classes?

Comment: Good call. Using auto layout solved it. Can you post an answer, Andy?

Comment: posted!  glad it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that your autolayout constraints are correct such that the UILabel is really positioned where you expect it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue once and I've solved it by not calling any methods to `cell.textLabel` property. Just don't set its text in any way.

Try it out and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UILabel *customLbl = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1000];
```